# How $this works in php ?

Tags: php, oop, this

I just want clarity of `$this` behaviour in PHP. From below program I want to know how can refer $this in class B to class A members, also on same time how can I use $this to refer the class B scope.

```
 <?php //php 7.0.8

  class A{ 
     public $name="test"; 
     public function func1(){
       echo $this->name="classAFunc";
    }
  }
 class B extends  A {
    public $name="classB";
    public function func2(){
      echo $this->name ;
   }   
 }

   $test = new B();
   echo $test->name; // classB
   echo $test->func1();//classAFunc
   echo $test->func2();//classAFunc //I want this should output classB

?>
```

If I am going somewhere wrong please point it out.  you refer here to play around : [run this program](https://rextester.com/live/MAPJVD7949)

Comment: please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming)) . `$this` is used to access the members(properties and methods) of the object of the current class (the class that you write the code in it's scope)

Comment: echo $this->name=“ClassAFunc”; is not valid syntax, perhaps use Google prior to asking questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //classAFunc //I want this should output classB

$this has nothing to do with achieving what you want, because function `func1` in your program changes the `name` property from `"classB"` to `"classAFunc"`, this is what you did here

```
echo $test->name; // classB
echo $test->func1();//classAFunc (func1 sets the name property to classAFunc)
echo $test->func2();//classAFunc //name property of the object is already changed by func1
```

you can call `func2()` before `func1()` to get what you want

or you can make `func2()` sets the name property, like this

```
public function func2(){
    echo $this->name = "classB";
}
```

Note: when `B` extended `A` their `name` property are merged, meaning the objects of `B` will have only 1 `name` property not 2!

Answer (score 0):

Change access modifier of $name variable to private.
ie; 
public $name="test"; to  private $name="test"; of class A

Comment: Can you explain this why such thing need to do ? cant  we solve this problem using constructor or super class concept @adhi

Comment: Altough, this is not a correct solution please explain your answer. You can't just simply sya: do it like this and not give an explaination.